# Date Control and Dataview filter on created date using Sharepoint designer

Tags: web-part, dataview

I know this is fairly simple but I am using SharePoint Foundation 2010 and I have a dataview web part and a calendar asp.net control. I created a parameter named SelectedDate and had it to get it's value from the calendar control. I then created a filter on the Dataview and filtered the created field by the selected date parameter but it never works for some reason I know it is a formatting issue but I don't have any idea on how to format the fields. I saw on the internet about the edit xlst checkbox in the filter selection but mine does not have that for some reason.

Comment: I just used the normal filter on the dataview it seems this is not straight forward as it really should be..

Answer (score 0):

Base on my research, we are not able to filter data view with the calendar control. When we add a parameter to receive data from the calendar control, this parameter actually gets nothing. So it will also unable to work as a filter.

Received From MSDN

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/3880ed19-1138-4822-a406-c44c8232309c/date-control-and-dataview-filter-on-created-date-using-sharepoint-designer